# How to increase size of a rectangle

Tags: c#, .net, gdi

I want to increase the size of my rectangle by 10 pixels. The following code seems not working. Assume sampleRect is my rectangle. Please let me know.

```
Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(
    sampleRect.X - 10, 
    sampleRect.Y - 10, 
    sampleRect.Width + 2*10, 
    sampleRect.Height + 2*10);
```

Comment: "Will the following code work" Are you serious?  Try it yourself and find out!

Comment: What do you mean "increase the size by 10 pixels"? Do you 1) Want to increase each side by 10 pixels 2) Do you want to increase the area by 10 pixels? Also, do you want the old rectangle to stay where it is centered or do you want it to grow sideways?

Comment: @Josh: Compiling & running the code on a slow machine obviously takes longer than asking on SO, I guess...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will work, but you can write the same thing more elegantly using the [`Inflate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6dsacz.aspx):

```
rect.Inflate(10, 10);
```

One important difference between your approach and `Inflate` method is that you create a new rectangle instance, while `Inflate` modifies an existing rectangle.

Comment: Rectangle is a value type; changes to it will not affect others as they (necessarily) will be copies.

Comment: @Ron Doesn't matter if it's a value type; it's not immutable

Comment: @Josh: It isn't a case of immutability; its a case of reference versus value typing.  `Inflate` mutates his existing `Rectangle` but no other code can hold a reference to it so they will always still hold the old value unless they re-read it. In Tomas's answer it was suggested that code holding references to the existing rectangle would automatically see the mutated value.

Comment: Good point about the value type - I deleted the last sentence (which would only make sense for reference types). Mutable value types are confusing!

Comment: @Ron My bad... I see what you mean now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would ask "will this work" - try it!

However,

```
 someRectangle.Inflate(10,20);
 //or 
 someRectangle.Inflate(10);
```

should work

Comment: I don't think there is any Inflate() method that takes a single argument like in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "grow by 10 pixels", here is what I would do:

```
int size = 10;
int halfSize = size/2;
Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(
    sampleRect.X - halfSize, 
    sampleRect.Y - halfSize, 
    sampleRect.Width + size, 
    sampleRect.Height + size);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will make a new Rectangle at x,y -10 compared to the sampleRect. To compensate you increase the Width and Height with 20.

I assume you are trying to increase the rectangle around the center, in that case you need to move the rectangle half of the new increase.

Example:

```
var sizeIncrease = 10;
var newX = sampleRect.X - 0.5 * sizeIncrease;
var newY = sampleRect.Y - 0.5 * sizeIncrease;
var newWidth = sampleRect.Width + sizeIncrease;
var newHeight = sampleRect.Height + sizeIncrease;
```

These values should give you what you are looking for

[Rectangle.Inflate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sy9hs3y.aspx) will also change the size around the center.